# Adding custom object with default property to dictionary

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

Consider the following:

```
Dim p As myObject 
Dim pDict As Scripting.Dictionary

p = New myObject
pDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

pDict.Item(Range("A" & i).Value) = p
```

`p` has a default property `DefProperty` via `Attribute Value.VB_UserMemId = 0`.

When I attempt to add `p` to `pDict`, only the default property gets added. The desired result is to add the *entirety* of `p` to `pDict`.

Calling `? p` is the same as calling `? p.DefProperty`, so in hindsight I can kind of understand why I am getting the wrong result -- what I don't understand is how to get the right one.

Comment: tbh, idk if this will work but you are going to have to `Set pDict.Item(Range("A" & i).Value) = p`. Subsequent changes to the `p` object (or setting to nothing) should be reflected in that dictionary item. Similar to setting a range object to a worksheet cell.

Comment: @Jeeped setting `p` to `Nothing` won't affect the dictionary item.

Comment: @Rory - good to know. thanks!

Comment: Naturally, it was something elementary. I had tried `Set` earlier, but removed it during troubleshooting an unrelated error. Thanks! I also have no need to null any of the objects, I am using `.Remove` as the state of the objects themselves are of no interest or value outside of the dictionary. @Jeeped submit as answer if you want the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to `Set pDict.Item(Range("A" & i).Value) = p`. Subsequent changes to the p object should be reflected in that dictionary item. Similar to setting a range type variable to a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).